# Break External Links Only for Specific Range in a Worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub BreakLinks()
  Dim wb As Workbook
  Set wb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
  If Not IsEmpty(wb.LinkSources(xlExcelLinks)) Then
     For Each link In wb.LinkSources(xlExcelLinks)
        wb.BreakLink link, xlLinkTypeExcelLinks
     Next link
  End If
End Sub
```

This code breaks all the external links the active workbook. How can I do it for a selected range in a particular sheet ?

Also, I want to first show the external links in a list(from the selected range), and then 2 buttons : 1 to delete them and 2nd to cancel.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`LinkSources(xlExcelLinks)` is a method of the `Workbook` - [MSDN Workbook.LinkSources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-linksources-method-excel), thus it is does not provide `.BreakLink` to cells.

However, you can loop through the cells with formulas in a given range (`givenRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)`) and check whether they contain `[`, which is needed for the link formula. If they have it, simply write the formulas as values:

```
Option Explicit

Sub BreakLinks()

    Dim givenRange As Range
    Set givenRange = Selection

    Dim myCell As Range
    For Each myCell In givenRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
         If InStr(myCell.Formula, "[") Then
            Debug.Print myCell.Address
            myCell.Value2 = myCell.Value2
         End If
    Next myCell

End Sub
```

Comment: You really are the best. Thanx a lot. Just one thing, Before removing the links I want to show all the external links from the selection, how to display them in userform?

Comment: @AmanDevrath - thanks. :) Concerning the displaying in userform, it is better to ask it as a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

- 1: Create a userform containing a list where all the external links will be listed
- 2: Set a custom range on a specific sheet and loop through the cells on that range using:

  ```
  .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
  ```
- 3: Find the cells that contain an external link using:

  ```
  InStr(1, rCell.Formula, "[") > 0 Then
  ```
- 4: Redim your array and store the cell.address in your array
- 5: Fill your listbox on your userform through your array (one could also just immediately fill the listbox in the initial loop)
- 6: Select a value in your listbox and use a button to delete the external link (use find or make sure you have stored your cell.address)
- 7: You could make your list a multiselect one offcourse.....

**EDIT** Basically what @Vityata explains in code aswell (beaten me to it :))